# Vue component set data value of child

Tags: properties, vuejs2, parent-child, vue-component

I am using vue carousel

https://ssense.github.io/vue-carousel/api/

It woks well but I need to resetthe carousel

[image]

I can see there is a value of current page and I think setting this to 0 would work as a reset. However these seems to be no exposed method to allow me to do this. Can I set it from the parent?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to set a data property on a child component, you can set a [`ref` attribute](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) on that child's tag and then access the child instance via `this.$refs`.

---

In your case, you could add a ref to the carousel tag like so:

```
<Carousel ref="carousel"/>
```

And then in you parent component's script, you can set the `currentPage` property of the child component like so:

```
this.$refs.carousel.currentPage = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

For reset purpose, another solution will be:

1. bind `:key` to data property for `VueCarousel`
2. when 'reset' event is triggered, just change data property to new value like below demo (`data property=resetIndex`).

Because When :key is changed to new one, it will re-mount the component.

```js
const buildSlideMarkup = (count) => {
 let slideMarkup = '';
  for (var i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
   slideMarkup += '<slide><span class="label">' + i + '</span></slide>'
  }
  return slideMarkup;
};

new Vue({
 el: '#example',
  components: {
   'carousel': VueCarousel.Carousel,
    'slide': VueCarousel.Slide
  },
  data() {
   return {
     resetIndex: 1
    }
  },
  methods: {
   reset: function () {
     this.resetIndex += 1
    }
  },
  template: '<div><button @click="reset()">Reset</button><carousel :key="resetIndex" :scrollPerPage="false">' + buildSlideMarkup(10) + '</carousel></div>'
});
```

```css
.VueCarousel-slide {
  position: relative;
  background: #42b983;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ssense.github.io/vue-carousel/js/vue-carousel.min.js"></script>

<div id="example"></div>
```