# How to use transitions on select option using Vue.js

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, css-transitions, vue-component

I have quick question regarding transitions with Vue.js.

In my boostrap template I'm trying to add one more select option dropdown based on selected option. So, I added change event on first select option. So, if I select *'first item'* then change classes and add dropdown in row, or else hides it.

> **Something like this:**
>
> ```
> selectTodo: function(e) {
>   let selectValue = e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].text
>
>   if (selectValue === 'Learn Vue') {
>     this.styleObject.display = 'unset';
>     this.col_md = 'form-group col-md-4';
>     this.showCropStageList = true;
>   }
>   else {
>     this.showCropStageList = false;
>     this.styleObject.display = 'none';
>     this.col_md = 'form-group col-md-6';
>     this.cropStageList = null;
>   }
> }
> ```

I managed to do that but I want *more* smoother transitions on the first two dropdowns.

I've managed to set up some [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Loque/akt0su98/) where you can see smooth slide transition for third select dropdown but if if I change select from *"Learn Vue"* to something else, the third dropdown hides it but without any animation as well.

You can see it in the snippet below, too!

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    todos: [
      { id:1 ,text: "Learn JavaScript", done: false },
      { id:2 ,text: "Learn Vue", done: false },
      { id:3 ,text: "Play around in JSFiddle", done: true },
      { id:4 ,text: "Build something awesome", done: true }
    ],
    col_md: 'form-group col-md-6',
    styleObject: {
          display: 'none'
        },
    showCropStageList: false,
  },
  methods: {
   toggle: function(todo){
     todo.done = !todo.done
    },
    selectTodo: function(e) {
    let selectValue = e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].text
    
        if (selectValue === 'Learn JavaScript') {
          
          this.styleObject.display = 'unset';
          this.col_md = 'form-group col-md-4';
          this.showCropStageList = true;
        }
        else {

          this.showCropStageList = false;
          this.styleObject.display = 'none';
          this.col_md = 'form-group col-md-6';
          this.cropStageList = null;
          
        }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.fade-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}

.fade-enter-active {
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.fade-leave {}

.fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 1s;
  opacity: 0;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <!-- Content here -->
  <div id="app">
    <div class="form-row">
      <transition name="fade" appear>
        <div v-bind:class=col_md>
          <label for="cropType" class="col-form-label-sm font-weight-bold">Select Learn Javascript </label>
          <select class="form-control" v-on:change="selectTodo" id="cropType" v-model="pickedCropType" @change="getCropsByType()">
              <option v-for="(todo, index) in todos" :key="index" :value="todo.id" >
                {{todo.text}}
              </option>
            </select>
        </div>
      </transition>
      <div v-bind:class=col_md>
        <label for="cropCulture" class="col-form-label-sm font-weight-bold">2. Second</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="cropCulture">
     <option v-for="(todo, index) in todos" :key="index" :value="todo.id" >
                {{todo.text}}
              </option>
            </select>
      </div>
      <transition 
      enter-active-class="animated fadeInLeft"
      leave-active-class="animated fadeOutLeft"
      >
        <div class="form-group col-md-4" v-if="showCropStageList" v-bind:class="{styleObject }">
          <label for="cropStage" class="col-form-label-sm font-weight-bold">3. Third</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="cropStage">
                <option v-for="(todo, index) in todos" :key="index" :value="todo.id" >
                {{todo.text}}
              </option>
              </select>
        </div>
      </transition>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see change class for first two dropdowns but without any transitions. So, is it possible to add some transitions for first two dropdowns?

**EDIT :**

---

*As you can see I'm changing class from *form-group col-md-6* to *form-group col-md-4*  and I' wondering if is it possible that that tranisition from md-6 to md-4 can be a bit smoother.*

https://jsfiddle.net/Loque/akt0su98/

Comment: what about [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akt0su98/79/)?

Comment: Close, I'm thinking is it possible to create in same row (as per required specification). But definitely good job for fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your codes, you directly update the class from `col-md-4` to `col-md-6` in `selectTodo`. It will cause first two `<div>` take **full width** of the row before 3rd div finishes its animation.

**The solution**, uses `this.$nextTick` and `setTimeout`.

when add the third div, delay execute show the third div before first two `<div>` finish their animations.

when remove the third div, delay apply `col-md-6` to the first two `<div>` before the third `<div>` finishes its animations.

Below is **one sample**: (**PS**: I used transition-group here, because it will be better for [Reusable Transitions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Reusable-Transitions))

**Warning**: Please test below demo under full page, otherwise bootstrap will treat it as extre-small screen (place each `<div>` in each row), though I think the effects in small screen is still not bad.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    todos: [
      { id:1 ,text: "Learn JavaScript", done: false },
      { id:2 ,text: "Learn Vue", done: false },
      { id:3 ,text: "Play around in JSFiddle", done: true },
      { id:4 ,text: "Build something awesome", done: true }
    ],
    col_md: 'form-group col-md-6',
    styleObject: {
          display: 'none'
        },
    showCropStageList: false,
    pickedCropType: ''
  },
  methods: {
    getCropsByType: function () {},
    toggle: function(todo){
        todo.done = !todo.done
    },
    selectTodo: function(e) {
        let selectValue = e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].text
      if (selectValue === 'Learn Vue') {
        this.col_md = 'form-group col-md-4';
        this.$nextTick(() => { //delay display the third div before first two div finish animation
            setTimeout(()=>{
            this.styleObject.display = 'unset';
            this.showCropStageList = true;
          }, 500)

        })
        
      }
      else {

        this.showCropStageList = false;
        this.styleObject.display = 'none';
        this.$nextTick(() => { //delay apply `md-6` to first two div before 3rd div finish animation
            setTimeout(()=>{
            this.col_md = 'form-group col-md-6';
          }, 1000)
            
        })
        
        this.cropStageList = null;

      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.sample {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.fade-item {
  transition: all 0.5s;
  display:inline-block;
}

.fade-enter {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-130px);

}

.fade-enter-active {
  transition: all 1.5s;
}

.fade-leave-to {
  transform: translateX(130px);
  opacity: 0;
  flex: 0 0 20%;
}

.fade-leave-active {
  transition: all 1s;
}

#app {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>

<!-- Content here -->
<div id="app">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="sample">
      <transition-group name="fade" tag="div" class="form-row">
        <div v-bind:class="col_md" :key="1" class="fade-item">
          <label for="cropType" class="col-form-label-sm font-weight-bold">Select Learn Javascript </label>
          <select class="form-control" v-on:change="selectTodo" id="cropType" v-model="pickedCropType" @change="getCropsByType()">
              <option v-for="(todo, index) in todos" :key="index" :value="todo.id" >
                {{todo.text}}
              </option>
            </select>
        </div>
      <div v-bind:class="col_md" :key="2" class="fade-item">
        <label for="cropCulture" class="col-form-label-sm font-weight-bold">2. Second</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="cropCulture">
     <option v-for="(todo, index) in todos" :key="index" :value="todo.id" >
                {{todo.text}}
              </option>
            </select>
      </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4 fade-item" v-if="showCropStageList" v-bind:class="{styleObject }" :key="3">
          <label for="cropStage" class="col-form-label-sm font-weight-bold">3. Third</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="cropStage">
                <option v-for="(todo, index) in todos" :key="index" :value="todo.id" >
                {{todo.text}}
              </option>
              </select>
        </div>
      </transition-group>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I was wondering about :key in div elements, can u please explain what is it for?

Comment: @Svinjica, you can look into [Vue Guide: Key](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key), [Vue Guide: transition between elements](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transitioning-Between-Elements), then key is required in `<transition-group>` ([Vue Guide: List Transition](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Transitions)).

Comment: Thank you, I ll look into that :)

Comment: @Svinjica Sometimes we will use `:key` to force-remount like [this demo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51676658/5665870), or like this demo in the comment [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akt0su98/79/) to implement forcely enter/leave transition (which is like v-if=false, then v-if=true).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a specific way to do in Vue but what you want can be easily achieved using some CSS magic. It is simple in a matter of fact, all you are going to do is add a class to your changing div let's say for example the class name is `transition` and in your CSS you define `transition` styles as follow:

```
.transition {
     transition: all 0.25s linear;
}
```

You can find an updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jq87yzd3/1/)

Note you can change the timing function `linear` and the time `0.25s` to suit your needs, you can read more about CSS transitions and effects [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions)

Comment: You are on right track but I'm still wondering is it possible to create in the same line (fiddle before was somehow close to the final solution)