# Component animation in a for

Tags: vue.js

I have child components of type input and I am trying to make them appear one by one when selecting the list, but it only applies the animation to me when I change selection

I add my code:

`

Elije tu Juego de la Suerte:

```
  <select name="games" id="games" v-model="selected">
    <option value="">Seleccionar ...</option>
    <option
      v-for="(option, index) in options"
      :key="index"
      :value="option.value"
    >
      {{ option.text }}
    </option>
  </select>


  <h2 v-if="selected !== ''">El juego seleccionado es: {{ selected }}</h2>

  <transition-group name="list" tag="p">
  <div class="content-input" v-if="selected == 'chispazo'">
    <Input @messageError="showErrorMessage" v-for="(n,index) in inputs.chispazo" :key="index" :name="index" class="list-item" />
  </div>
  </transition-group>

<transition name="fade">
  <div class="error" v-show="!isValid">{{ message }}</div>
</transition>

</template>

<script>

import Input from './Input.vue'

export default {
  name: "Favorito",
  components: {
      Input,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      selected: "",
      options: [
        { text: "Chispazo", value: "chispazo", mount: 3 },
        { text: "Melate Retro", value: "melate_retro", mount: 5 },
        { text: "Gana Gato", value: "gana_gato", mount: 3 },
        { text: "Tris", value: "tris", mount: 4 },
      ],
      inputs: {
        chispazo: 20,
        melateretro: 8,
        ganagago: 10,
        tris: 3,
      },
      message: '',
      isValid: true
    };
  },
  methods: {
      showErrorMessage(value){
          console.log('--> recibiendo del padre:', value)
          this.message = value[0]
          this.isValid = value[1]
      }
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.content-input {
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
  padding: 12px;
}

.error {
  color: red;
}

.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .5s
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to /* .fade-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */ {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 1s
}


.list-item {
  display: inline-block;
}
.list-enter-active, .list-leave-active {
  transition: all 1s;
}
.list-enter, .list-leave-to /* .list-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */ {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(30px);
}
</style>
```

`

How can I add animations to components within a for?

Thank you very much for your support

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this?

```html
  <div class="content-input" v-if="selected == 'chispazo'">
    <transition-group name="list" tag="p">
      <Input @messageError="showErrorMessage" v-for="(n,index) in inputs.chispazo" :key="index" :name="index" class="list-item" />
    </transition-group>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks IVO GELOV, I made the change but now it does not apply any effect...

I was researching and found this: [How to use transitions on select option using Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51720162/how-to-use-transitions-on-select-option-using-vue-js)

My solution was create animation with select element html.